# Ender 3 Z axis not working?

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis

I recently got an Ender 3 3D printer for my birthday, and while I've had a lot of problems with it, there's one that I haven't been able to fix.

I can control the Z-axis, but whenever I go to print anything, it never does anything. The X- and Y-axis work just fine.

Any solutions?

Comment: Use the control menu and see if you can Extrude anything at all, maybe your material isn't feeding down into the nozzle correctly to be melted and pushed out.    Is the bed and the nozzle heating up correctly?

Comment: Does the model look correct in the slicer? E.g. Cura shows a picture of what is meant to printed. Does the z-axis motor make strange sounds?

Comment: What slicer are you using?